# How do I get around the error in R package building

Tags: r, installation, command-prompt, r-package, build-error

I built a R package using the build command shown below but now I can't build another with it. Please inform me on what is causing the error. The code is as follows:

C:\Users\abu\Documents> R CMD build analysiscb
The system cannot find the path specified.

- checking for file 'analysiscb/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
- preparing 'analysiscb':
- checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
- installing the package to process help pages
  -----------------------------------
  The system cannot find the path specified.
- installing *source* package 'analysiscb' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'analysiscb'
  finding HTML links ... done
  analysiscb-package                      html
  bcr.decide                              html
  npv.eval                                html
  rbcr                                    html
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
  ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
- DONE (analysiscb)
  -----------------------------------
  ERROR: package installation failed

C:\Users\abu\Documents>

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I renamed the functions, rerun the package skeleton and accessed the cmd as the administrator. Touché! It was successful.